# Which content management to choose when developing is crucial

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, umbraco

I have been evaluating DNN over a few months. It has it´s pros and cons. I find it hard to evaluate systems by reading articles and don´t have time to check them all on my own.

What are your general feeling about this?

As my background is with .net, which system would you choose?

Also, does anybody know if these pages at stack overflow is based on a CMS and if so which?

Comment: you are getting down voted because this site is about code, you are asking a question that is opinion based, does not have a clear answer, and it is not code related.  I had the same situation as you a few years ago when I started with DNN.  Best bet is to google and test (A LOT).  If you don't have time for that then you don't have time to learn a new CMS.  I personally use DNN because it is .NET and it is very flexible, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: Thanks, J King. :)
I don´t care too much about the votes, but still find it a bit strange as most developers I know are opinionated on things like framework and language. Regarding having time to check out different systems, I´d rather spend that time on coding. ;)

Comment: You are right, they are opinionated, and one of the things they are opinionated about is this forum.  There are other Stack overflow sites that can help in terms of the questions you asked, this one is coding problems specific.  I recommend DNN but you will most likley have to work to learn both the skinning and module development both in order to use it to its true potential.  Its relatively straightforward once you understand it.  Good luck.  Try this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanx again, J King! I have set up my module development with DNN. Somwhow I seem to run into problems with plugins not working in DNN witch is working in fiddle and it frustrates me. I depend very much on special adapted and developed code, but the thought was to get away easy with messaging/notifications, user management etc from DNN. What´s your experience with js-plugins in DNN - do they basically work or do you often get trapped in conflicts and non-working functionality?

Comment: I would suggest opening a question for specific issues you are facing, it might help you to discover more "global" conditions that are affecting your plugins.  That's to broad a question to answer here. Having said that, JS/J-Query does take some tinkering to get right for my module development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everyone would rather spend more time criticizing your post than answering it, I'll give it a shot.

You have a few options with building a portal.  Either go with an established, open source portal (like DNN), look into some paid solutions or build your own.

1. Open Source - I've worked with DNN and MojoPortal.  DNN is a little slower and has a few more requirements to develop skins and modules, but it has A LOT more features and some of the free/paid modules are really cool.  Overall, DNN wins here, but if you don't need a large portal and you want to keep development really simple, MojoPortal might be better.  MojoPortal has a few nice features that makes it easier to configure.
2. Open Source (Other) - There are tons of them out there. Orchard is one I'm thinking of because I'm interested in MVC.  But, it's still young in terms of features and support.
3. Umbraco - I can't really speak to this because I have not used it, but it does have some popularity.
4. Build it - This is an option and allows the most flexibility, but it takes a lot of time and so many features that are built into these portals could be left out.  Role based access, page management, page/module permissions, downloadable modules, profile/profile properties, file management, skinning, acct management, menu management, event logs, etc
5. I left out non .NET solutions like ones based on PHP, Grails, etc because you are a .NET developer.  There is plenty out there, but sticking to .NET will help speed your development up.... unless you are just wanting to learn something new.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your comments about Umbraco are inaccurate and you really should read up on things like this before handing out the advice. Umbraco is not a "paid solution", it is completely free. It is also open source, and you will find that almost all your support comes from the community, not the Umbraco core team. The core team are incredibly helpful but Umbraco actually has one of the most helpful communities I know of. The core team release updates to the CMS on a fairly frequent basis that often include community submitted fixes.

Comment: @Digbyswift You are right.  I haven't looked at Umbraco in a while and I may be confusing it with another framework.  I thought they were charging for documentation and videos, but they are not.  I removed that from my post.  I'll definitely take another look at it.  Thx

Comment: @L_7337 Appreciated, and definitely take a look at it. It's my tool of choice at the moment because of how much I can get done so quickly. Plus, you should heck out the v7 due to be released soon.